# Absurd value being displayed for the variable 'largest'

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int phy,geo,i,highest,largest;
    int arr[2]={phy,geo};

    printf("marks for physics : ");
    scanf("%d",&phy);

    printf("marks for geo : ");
    scanf("%d",&geo);

    largest = arr[0];

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            largest = arr[i];
        }
    }

    // Print out the Result
    printf("\nLargest Element : %d", largest);

    return(0);
}
```

I am getting absurd values for the variable 'largest' . It's always the same value no matter what inputs I put in. The purpose of it is to calculate the largest number out of the two inputted numbers.

Comment: "absurd values" Clarify, please?

Comment: I get the value 36 no matter what I input @MDXF

Comment: You're declaring `arr[2] = {phy,geo};` before `phy` and `geo` have values.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. And `int arr[2]={phy,geo};` does not connect the array with values you will enter in the future, it uses the - uninitialised - values they have at the time you instantiated the array.

Answer (score 1):

You're filling your array with uninitialized numbers, that's the source of your "absurd value", then you put your input into variables that are never read, hence why your inputs never change the output.

Try this instead:

```
printf("marks for physics : ");
scanf("%d", &arr[0]);

printf("marks for geo : ");
scanf("%d", &arr[1]);
```

Comment: Darn; Just about to write the exact same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Get five spaces in memory filled with whatever was there to begin with:

```
int phy,geo,i,highest,largest;
```

Get three spaces in memory, set the last one to null (to show it's the end of an array), and copies the values from two of the earlier five uninitialized spaces into an array:

```
int arr[2]={phy,geo};
```

Get two numbers that are input, and write them into two of the five spaces you originally got from memory:

```
printf("marks for physics : ");
scanf("%d",&phy);
printf("marks for geo : ");
scanf("%d",&geo);
```

Fill the fifth space in memory with a copy of the value you copied from the first uninitialized space in memory memory into the first element of the array:

```
largest = arr[0];
```

For each element in the array (beginning with the one you just copied), if the element is larger than what you've copies into the fifth space in memory, copy it into that space in memory.

```
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > largest) {
     largest = arr[i];
  }
 }
```

So what you've done is copied uninitialized spots in memory into an array, then taken inputs and written them to those spots in memory, then looked for the largest element in the array. This gives you weird results because you are comparing whatever values happened to be in memory when your program started running.

Answer (score 1):

With the statement

```
int arr[2]={phy,geo};
```

you are basically initializing the array with the current values of `phy` and `geo` which are as yet uninitialized.

When you later load values through `scanf`, these won't be reflected in `arr`.
You need to modify the code as follows:

```
printf("marks for physics : ");
scanf("%d",&phy);
arr[0] = phy;

printf("marks for geo : ");
scanf("%d",&geo);
arr[1] = geo;
```

Comment: That formatting is hard to read. Please indent 4 spaces for code blocks or `backtics` for inline.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[2]={phy,geo};
```

This doesn't mean "`arr` is an array of whatever values `phy` and `geo` will hold in the future".

It means "`arr` is an array of whatever values `phy` and `geo` hold *now*".

And those values are indeterminate because, when you creat `arr`, neither `phy` or `geo` have been initialised yet.